# Running Excel Via Python to Fetch Blommberg data

Tags: python, win32com, bloomberg

Trying to Fetch some data from Bloomberg terminal by driving excel programmatically via python here is the code I'm working with.
I have a list of Bloomberg Ticker Codes already so I want to use this tickers to fetch the various fixed income fields.
I begin by creating a create the workbook and then adding the tickers to the first column.
When I proceed to run the excel programmatically using win32com I get an error regarding macros what am I missing?

```
import win32com.client
import xlsxwriter
import xlwings as xl
import datetime

path = 'mypath/TempData.xlsx'
work_sheet_name = "Data"

Excelworkbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path)
worksheet = Excelworkbook.add_worksheet(work_sheet_name)

#List of tickers
Tickers = ['1124Z MK EQUITY','TD CN EQUITY','MIZC JP EQUITY','N91 LN EQUITY',
              'COST US EQUITY','6857Z LN EQUITY','DZBK GR EQUITY','55601Z US EQUITY','BMO CN EQUITY']

worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Tickers')

row = 1
col = 0

for ticker in Tickers:    
    worksheet.write(row, col,ticker)   
    row += 1

Excelworkbook.close()

#Connect to Excel.
bb = 'C:/blp/API/Office Tools/BloombergUI.xla'
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")  
xl.Workbooks.Open(bb)
xl.AddIns("Bloomberg Excel Tools").Installed = False

wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path) 
data_Sheet = wb.Worksheets(work_sheet_name)

xl.Visible = False
xl.EnableEvents = False
xl.DisplayAlerts = False 

# Open the Excel file and read the tickers from the first column
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path)
data_Sheet = wb.Worksheets(work_sheet_name)
max_row = data_Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

tickers = []
for row in range(2, max_row+1):
    ticker = data_Sheet.Cells(row, 1).Value
    tickers.append(ticker)

# Fetch data for each ticker using Bloomberg formulas
for i, ticker in enumerate(tickers):
    # Retrieve the coupon yield
    yield_cell = f'B{i+1}'
    coupon_yield = xl.Run("=@BDP(\"" + ticker + "\",\"CPN\")")
    data_Sheet.Range(yield_cell).Value = coupon_yield
    
    # Retrieve the maturity date
    maturity_cell = f'C{i+1}'
    maturity_raw = xl.Run("=@BDP(\"" + ticker + "\",\"MATURITY\")")
    maturity_date = datetime.strptime(maturity_raw, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
    data_Sheet.Range(maturity_cell).Value = maturity_date

# Save and close the Excel file
wb.Save()
wb.Close()
xl.Quit()
```

this is the error i keep getting.
Tried enabling macros but this still happens.

```
line 44668, in Run
    return self._ApplyTypes_(259, 1, (12, 0), ((12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12,     self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Cannot run the macro \'=@BDP("1124Z MK EQUITY","CPN")\'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Comment: Things to try: 1. Make sure you're running script from *Admin* shell. 2. Make sure you don't have the Excel open before running script. 3. Try to use the `*.xlsm` extension for your Excel file. 4. Check that you have the following path: `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop` (idea from [here](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/217898/execution-of-excel-vba-using-python-scri.html).) 5. Check other settings in excel. (Scripting enabled etc etc.)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.run  The `Run` function takes the macro as the first parameter, and then the arguments.  Try `xl.Run('BDP',ticker,'CPN')`. But that's the least of your worries: you will run into the issue that the Excel Bloomberg calls are asynchronous. Better to pull the Bloomberg data directly into python (eg using the `xbbg` package), then write to the worksheet cells, using your xlsx writer of choice. Then you don't need `win32com` at all.

Comment: Also ... all your tickers are equities ... you are unlikely to get coupon or maturity

Comment: @DS_London I tried  the `xbbg`  but I  ran into a challenge where when I make say bulk request(1000 issuers\tickers   4 times within a day) it starts returning empty response for the requests I make after that, I thought its something to do with the limit on the number of requests  hence the excel alternative. 
For the tickers those should be corporates bonds.

Comment: The data usage is the same whether you use Excel or Python ... it all goes through the same pipe to Bloomberg. If you are using a lot of tickers in one call (with `xbbg`) then the request might time out before you get the data back. Try breaking the queries down into smaller chunks.

Comment: @DS_London on the first suggestion on using `xl.Run`  after replacing my above code with this `coupon_yield = xl.Run('BDP',ticker,'CPN')` the loop somehow doesn't exit and still doesn't fetch the data.

Answer (score 1):

The OP is using something of a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

It is easier and faster to pull the Bloomberg data into Python (eg using the `xbbg` package) and then use the `pandas` DataFrame to write to the `.xlsx` file.

```
from xbbg import blp
import pandas as pd

tickers = ['CT2 Govt','CT5 Govt','CT10 Govt','CT30 Govt']
fields = ['CPN','MATURITY']
filePath = 'c:\\temp\\myfile.xlsx'

#This stops the writer formatting the output
from pandas.io.formats import excel
excel.ExcelFormatter.header_style = None

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filePath,mode='a',engine='openpyxl',
                           if_sheet_exists='overlay',date_format='DD/MM/YYY')

df = blp.bdp(tickers,fields)
df.sort_values(by='maturity').to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Data')

writer.close()
```

With the output in Excel:

[image]

One of the main reasons **not** to use `win32com` to automate Excel is that the Bloomberg functions are *asynchronous*. This means that the Excel call returns immediately, and the actual data arrives later. Thus you will likely end up with a set of `N/A Requesting Data ...` results rather than values. Solutions then usually have to resort to looping in order to check the data has arrived.

Comment: Certainly a better solution but for a simple request like that I think one could directly use Bloomberg's excel API.